# Lex match an angle bracket literally

Tags: regex, lex

I can't seem to get this lex regex working:

```
%{
#include"y.tab.h"
%}

%option yylineno

/* regular definitions */
angle_bracket_start "<"

%%
angle_bracket_start /*swallow it, do nothing!*/{}
%%
```

But when I test it with

```
lex lex.l
gcc lex.yy.c -lfl
```

I got:

```
$ ./a.out
<
<    <--- If it prints out the "<", it means lex can't parse it, right?
^C
```

I'm asking this because I need a regex which matches verbatimly

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
```

But I always get syntax error because lex decides it can't parse and thus throw out the `<` and parse `script` as an id

Comment: There is really no need to use definitions in a case like this. Just put `"<"` into your rule. It's easier to read and less work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer to a definition, use curly braces (`{}`) around the name:

```
angle_bracket_start "<"

%%
{angle_bracket_start}    /*swallow it, do nothing!*/
```

without the curly braces, it is looking for the literal string `angle_bracket_start` in the input...

Comment: Well.. Thank you so much. It's clearly a brain fart but I don't know how long I'll be stuck without your answer..